# Setup react-ga for conversion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I'm trying to configure google analytics for my react application. In my work I use the react-ga plugin. In all instructions they write that in the ReactGS.initialize() method, the arguments must be in the format UA-XXXXXX-XX, but for conversion, the format AW-XXXXXXXXX is needed.
Code example in docs:

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01');
```

In my case:

```
// initialize
App.js (main file)

useEffect(() => {
   ReactGA.initialize('AW-XXXXXXXXX');
}, [params])
```

```
// call when event is done
api.js

POST METHOD
ReactGA.ga('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})
```

But code below is not working.
Maybe someone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it

Comment: What your are referring for this `ReactGA.ga('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 , I use that code in POST method. I'm tracking events on my application so when the some event is done I have to run that code.
```
 axios.post('/api/request/new-request', { name, number })
    .then(() => {
      ReactGA.ga('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-730521646/qJ3JCJKA6KUBEK7Aq9wC'})
    })
```

Comment: @ravibagul91 or did you mean something else

Comment: Yes I have not seen such event. So trying to understand what is {'send_to': 'AW-730521646/qJ3JCJKA6KUBEK7Aq9wC'} part.

Comment: Because once initialized your normal event is like this, `ReactGA.event({
  category: 'User',
  action: 'Created an Account'
});`

Comment: @ravibagul91 That's my fault. They track events in multi-page sites without the react-ga plugin, and I tried to combine them.
If this is not the right approach, then I have no idea how to track events and pass on the parameters I need (arg: send_to). The documentation does not describe my case.
Do you have any ideas how to solve my problem or where I have to looking for necessary information?

Comment: Try this - `ReactGA.event({ category: 'conversion', action: 'AW-730521646/qJ3JCJKA6KUBEK7Aq9wC' })`

Comment: Actually your requirement is not so clear to me. May be you need to edit post with more relavant example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ravibagul91 thanks so much. I'll try it

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this.. To track conversion through react-ga

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracking in Google Analytics and Google Ads are different. Currently, it's not possible to track directly from `react-ga` to Google Ads, see: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/270

You can add Google Ads' tracking code to `<script>` tags directly to your `index.html` or use [Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). Then you can call `window.gtag`.

What I'd recommend instead though, as you're already using Google Analytics with `react-ga`, is to use a Google Analytics Goal as a Conversion metric is Google Ads. Follow these steps:

- Link Google Analytics and Google Ads: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961
- Set goal in Google Analytics: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en
- Import goal in Google Ads: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en

This way you only have to worry about tracking with a single service.

Comment: any updates for react-ga4 maybe?